# IOS 7 scroll view image slider memory leak

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview, uiimageview, automatic-ref-counting

I have a scrollView with three images in it, in the first view shown by my app. I use that as an image slider and to create it, in viewDidLoad I do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kNumImages; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"craft%d.jpg", i]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
```

When using the profiler tool and the memory leak tool, when the app starts, after 7 seconds, after viewDidLoad, when I'm already seeing the screen fully loaded, profiler shows a memory leak peak. Something like __ | __. I can't understand why is that. Am using ARC.

Edit:

I created an empty project (single viewController), and using storyboard added an imageView. Still using the storyboard I set the image property to be an image from the assets catalog and NO leak shown... if I choose image not from the assets, leak shown.

Edit 2:

No leak peaks running on the device.

Comment: How many images are you loading? What's the value of kNumImages?

Comment: Do you have arc based project?

Comment: Hey, kNumImages is 3... I use ARC. I use the exact same slider in a detail view and no leak is shown.

Comment: See my edit... Created an empty project with storyboard and added an imageView. When choosing an image not from the assets catalog (jpg or png) the leak is shown.

Comment: I had the same problem, then I put the image in an assets catalog as you say in your edit, and the leak went away.